# Pythons platform.system() gives me str object has no attribute system but only in script

Tags: python, platform

If I do like this in the python prompt:

```
import platform

platform.system()
```

I get Linux as expected.

However if I do like this in my script:

```
import platform
if(platform.system() == "windows"):
 print x
else:
  print y
```

I just get this error messsage.
AttributeError: str object has no attribute system

I am quite new to Python but this puzzles me a bit so if anyone can point to the problem I would be grateful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Somewhere in your script you have a variable called `platform` that shadows the module with the same name.

Comment: I tried to fix this same issue by using `from sys import platform as plat` and then `print(plat.system())` but the error remains despite the rename? I dont know of any variables called `platform`